# select image from a series of image and place it to canvas in 1 function

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas, onclick

I am Alex and this is my first stack overflow question.

I have the below script.
-This script gets images from an api.
-For each image received from the api, an  element is created
-for each image, a class attribute is created
-for each image, an id attribute is created.
-for each image, a  element is created. For each of the , I dynamically append an onclick event. each onclick is associated with its own function.

the anchor1,2,3,4 and 5 function are made so each time a user clicks a selected image, that image is then place into a canvas. When that is done, the color thief js kicks in and displays the color palette of the image selected.

All of that works perfectly.

What I would like to do is instead of having a function for each image, is to have 1 function that would place the image clicked into the canvas.
Basically i think my code can be made less redundant.

```
// search the collection using a JSON call
function search(query) {
  return $.getJSON("https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/api/en/collection?q=Q&key=r4nzV2tL&imgonly=True&ps=5&format=json".replace("Q", query));

}

var searchBtn = document.getElementById("search");
searchBtn.addEventListener("click", doSearch);

var resultD = document.getElementById("result");
var searchField = document.getElementById("query");

//search function starts here
function doSearch() {
    $("#result").show(); // result div to show when making new search
    resultD.innerHTML = "";
    var searchString = searchField.value;
    if (searchString !== "") {
     search(searchString).done(function(data) {
      for (var artObj in data.artObjects) {
      var rImg = document.createElement("img"); // create the image
      rImg.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "Anonymous"); //needed so I can actually copy the image for later use
      rImg.setAttribute("class", "imageClass"); //needed so I can actually copy the image for later use
      var link = document.createElement("a"); // create the link
      link.setAttribute('href', '#'); // set link path
      // link.href = "www.example.com"; //can be done this way too
      rImg.src = data.artObjects[artObj].webImage.url; // the source of the image element is the url from rijks api
       link.appendChild(rImg); // append image to link
       resultD.appendChild(link); // append link with image to div
       resultD.innerHTML += data.artObjects[artObj].title; // this is the title from rijks api
       $("#result img").each(function (i, image){ //for each image create a different id
        image.id = "image" + (i + 1);
      });
     $("#result a").each(function (i, anchor){ //for each anchor create a different id
      anchor.id = "anchor" + (i + 1);
        anchor.setAttribute('onclick', "anchor" + (i + 1)+'();return false;'); // set link path
        //return false needed so to avoid page jump
      });
     resultD.innerHTML += "<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>";
   }   
 });
}
}//search function ends here



//for each image create size matching canvas
function anchor1(){

  var c=document.getElementById("drawing1");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  var img=document.getElementById("image1"); 
  c.height = img.height ;
  c.width = img.width ;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,c.width, c.height);
  $("#result").hide();
setTimeout(function() { //timeout for image load to canvas - start
  var colorThief = new ColorThief();
  var color = colorThief.getPalette(img, 18);
  var newHTML = $.map(color, function(value) {
    return('<div style="background-color:rgb(' + value.join(', ') + ')">&nbsp;</div>'+'<br>');
  });
  $("#colors").html(newHTML.join(''));
}, 500); //timeout for image load to canvas - ends
}

function anchor2(){

  var c=document.getElementById("drawing1");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  var img=document.getElementById("image2");
  c.height = img.height ;
  c.width = img.width ;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,c.width, c.height);
  $("#result").hide();
  setTimeout(function() { //timeout for image load to canvas - start
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var color = colorThief.getPalette(img, 18);
    var newHTML = $.map(color, function(value) {
      return('<div style="background-color:rgb(' + value.join(', ') + ')">&nbsp;</div>'+'<br>');
    });
    $("#colors").html(newHTML.join(''));
}, 500); //timeout for image load to canvas - ends
}

function anchor3(){

  var c=document.getElementById("drawing1");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  var img=document.getElementById("image3");
  c.height = img.height ;
  c.width = img.width ;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,c.width, c.height);
  $("#result").hide();
  setTimeout(function() { //timeout for image load to canvas - start
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var color = colorThief.getPalette(img, 18);
    var newHTML = $.map(color, function(value) {
      return('<div style="background-color:rgb(' + value.join(', ') + ')">&nbsp;</div>'+'<br>');
    });
    $("#colors").html(newHTML.join(''));
}, 500); //timeout for image load to canvas - ends
}

function anchor4(){

  var c=document.getElementById("drawing1");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  var img=document.getElementById("image4");
  c.height = img.height ;
  c.width = img.width ;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,c.width, c.height);
  $("#result").hide();
  setTimeout(function() { //timeout for image load to canvas - start
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var color = colorThief.getPalette(img, 18);
    var newHTML = $.map(color, function(value) {
      return('<div style="background-color:rgb(' + value.join(', ') + ')">&nbsp;</div>'+'<br>');
    });
    $("#colors").html(newHTML.join(''));
}, 500); //timeout for image load to canvas - ends
}

function anchor5(){

  var c=document.getElementById("drawing1");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  var img=document.getElementById("image5");
  c.height = img.height ;
  c.width = img.width ;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,c.width, c.height);
  $("#result").hide();
  setTimeout(function() { //timeout for image load to canvas - start
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var color = colorThief.getPalette(img, 18);
    var newHTML = $.map(color, function(value) {
      return('<div style="background-color:rgb(' + value.join(', ') + ')">&nbsp;</div>'+'<br>');
    });
    $("#colors").html(newHTML.join(''));
}, 500); //timeout for image load to canvas - ends
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to utilize the `.on` event with jquery which allows you to deal with dynamic data which is basically what you are dealing with.

You are generating different `<a>` links with an individual `id` to call your different functions like (anchor1, anchor2...) with `$("#result a").each(function (i, anchor){ //for each anchor create a different id anchor.id = "anchor" + (i + 1);`

Instead of generating a different id for each `<a>` just give them the same value, but make it a class and not a id. Id's should always be unique and never repeat, classes can be repeated. For instance `<a class="anchor"><...</a>`

Then when you want to deal with the data from that particular record/image you would call it as such.

```
$(document).on('click','.anchor', function () {

});
```

So here is a working example you can start with.

```
<a class="anchor" data-id="1">...</a>


$(document).on('click','.anchor', function () {
    var anchor_id = $(this).attr('data-id').val();

    var c=document.getElementById("drawing1");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById("image"+anchor_id); //this will attach the id for that image here
    c.height = img.height ;
    c.width = img.width ;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,c.width, c.height);
    $("#result").hide();
    setTimeout(function() { //timeout for image load to canvas - start
        var colorThief = new ColorThief();
        var color = colorThief.getPalette(img, 18);
        var newHTML = $.map(color, function(value) {
        return('<div style="background-color:rgb(' + value.join(', ') + ')">&nbsp;       </div>'+'<br>');
        });
        $("#colors").html(newHTML.join(''));
     }, 500); //timeout for image load to canvas - ends
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/

http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick. I did use the '$("#result a").each(function' to create multiple and different data-id and it worked. i am learning a lot. thanks a ton Cesar!!